# Deployment Architecture for cloud & on premise b2b application

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, architecture

I'm working on a SaaS application which at the moment is cloud only. It's a traditional Java web application which we deploy to AWS. We rely on AWS concepts like RDS, S3, ELB, Autoscaling and for infrastructure provisioning AMIs, Cloudformation, Ansible and CodeDeploy.

There is now more and more demand for on-premise deployments by potential clients.

Are there any common approaches to package b2b applications for on-premise deployments?

My first thought would be to containerize the app infrastructure (web server, database, etc) and assume a client would be able run images. What are you guys doing and how do you tackle HA and DR aspects which come with cloud infrastructure like AWS?

Comment: In general Containers are a good start, but aside from that I can only tell you: it depends. (This is an indication that this question is too broad)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Maurice. In other words, there's no industry accepted packaging.

Comment: The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from. There is no one size fits all solution if that's your question ;-) - Containers are a fairly common approach, but there are dozens of other valid solutions depending on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tackling a similar problem at the moment and there really is no one-fits all answer. Designing software for cloud-nativity comes with a lot of architectural design decisions to use technologies on offer by the platform (as you have with S3, RDS, etc) which ultimately do not cross-over to majority of on-premise deployments.

Containerising your application estate is great for cross-cloud and some hybrid cloud portability but there is no guarantee that a client is using containerised work-loads on their on-premise data centre which makes the paradigm still a way off the target of supporting both seamlessly.

I find another issue is that the design principles behind cloud-hosted software are vastly different to those on-premise, with static resource requirements, often a lack of ability to scale etcetera (ironically some of the main reasons you would move a software solution to a cloud environment) so trying to design for both is a struggle and I'm guessing we will end up with a sub-optimal solution unless we decide to favour one and treat the other as a secondary concern.

I'm thinking maybe the best cross-breed solution is to concentrate on containerisation for cloud hosts taking into account the products and services on offer (and in the roadmap) - and then for making the same software available to clients who wish to use on-premise datacenters still.... perhaps they could be offered VM Images with the software solution packaged in... then make this available on a client portal for them with instructions on installation/configuration.

... I wish everyone would just use Kubernetes already! :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm facing exactly the same challenges, striking the balance between cloud-native and still leaving a door open for on-premise deployments. At the moment my app architecture is relatively traditional and I think many aspects like RDS, S3 are black boxes and can be replaced by containers. However it will push more on the deployment environment (i.e. provide a HA database, provide a HA filestorage, mirror auto scaling). 
Reading the comment, containerization will definitely be my approach, minimum being a docker image with the app installed.